# How to delay a code to run after user touch the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a Tap game,  tap the screen to start the game.
I have this code and I need to make this animation to start after tap the screen. Now Is running when the game are loading (without tap the screen). What I need to change it to start this animation after the user tab (touch) on the screen? Thanks for your help.

```
[super viewDidLoad];

// Set Delay on Animations when Game Start - Animations Area ***** PERFORMS ****** 0.1
[self performSelector:@selector(Animation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a tap gesture recognizer to your view and start the animation in the selector.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];


     UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRg = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(beginAnimation)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRg];

}


   -(void) beginAnimation
{
    // Set Delay on Animations when Game Start - Animations Area ***** PERFORMS ****** 0.1
    [self performSelector:@selector(Animation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

If you want to begin animation on touch begins then override `-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and start the animation there.

Comment: Alternatively, he could just set touches enabled and implement `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` in his view, then start the animations there. Admittedly, it requires that he subclasses the view...

Comment: @NicolasMiari, I have added that option towards the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Tap Gesture to screen.If you have UIViewController and you want to start animation on tap of UIViewController view tap then you can use this code as it is or you can change the view on which you want tap and start animation

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = 
      [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                              action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];  //Replace the self.view if you want to add single tap on another view with your view refrence
 }

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

   [self Animation]; //You should rename this method as animation.Follow naming conventions.
}
```